# Freebase search_api and excluding results by specified type

Tags: api, search, freebase, mql

is anyone know, how to exclude some topics with specified type(s) using search api and mql?

For example i'm try to find all topics "Voodoo People", and exclude only those, that have composition and release types, and sort result by score desc: http://tinyurl.com/3tjkb7y.
Sorting work perfect, but i can't find functionality for excluding :( 
I'm try to use mql_filter: http://tinyurl.com/644xkow, but releases still there.
And one more question: i see in type_strict param possible values: "all", "any", "should". But there is no value "not" or "not in". Is needed result can be obtained in any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax that you're looking for is *"optional" : "forbidden"*. In your query that would look like this:

```
[{
  "search": {
    "query": "Voodoo People",
    "score": null,
    "mql_filter": [{
      "type": {
        "id":       "/music/release",
        "optional": "forbidden"
      }
    }]
  },
  "name":  null,
  "id":    null,
  "type":  [],
  "/common/topic/notable_for": {
  },
  "limit": 15,
  "sort":  "-search.score"
}]​
```