# Restricting a freebase search query to results that have only the type "/common/topic"

Tags: api, search, filter, freebase

I'm trying to find results from a search where all the topics in the result have only the type: "/common/type". For instance, if I search for "BBQ Chicken" I'd like to get back *"/en/barbecue_chicken"* as the first, and, perhaps, only result, since it has no other types associated with it besides *"/common/topic"*

I did see an answer to a similar question at: 
[Freebase search_api and excluding results by specified type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883933/freebase-search-api-and-excluding-results-by-specified-type) but I understand that mql_filter is no longer supported in the new api. 
Also, I found an mql query that returns all topics that have only type "/common/topic" in the MQL Cookbook, but haven't been able to find a way to use it in search.

http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_Cookbook#Find_untyped_topics_.28or_which_only_have_a_given_type.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freebase is a free open database that anyone can contribute to. Assuming that "BBQ Chicken" will never have another type assigned to it is not a good assumption to make. In fact, you should probably assume that over time most Freebase topics will acquire some type in addition to /common/topic.

I've gone ahead and added the type [/food/dish](http://www.freebase.com/view/food/dish) so that now you can reliably find BBQ Chicken using the Search API like this:

https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=BBQ+Chicken&type=/food/dish

Comment: Thanks Shawn! I'm really trying to match keywords to entities in FB using some additional information about the types of information I'm looking for. In my example, I am searching for food/beverage/menu items and in my general query I restrict results to include the relevant types (/food/beverage, /food/food etc.) This works well most of the time, but there are several instances where the best answer in Freebase is a topic that has only */common/topic* and I want to be able to identify those cases, but including */common/topic* in the query filter makes the restrictions too general.

Comment: Feel free to log into Freebase and add relevant types to the topics that are missing them. Not only does it improve your app, but it improves the quality of Freebase data for everyone.

Comment: sure, I intend to do so, but I need a way to find these topics first. I've been looking at the results of some of the matches which is what alerted me to the issue in the first place, but I'm looking for a way to find them programatically. I can then decide if those topics are relevant and add the appropriate types to them. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. You might also be interested in the Refine Reconciliation API (http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/ReconciliationServiceApi) which was designed specifically for that task. Alternately, you can just figure out a list of incompatible types and filter those out in the search query.

Comment: cool, I will try the Refine API, it looks like exactly what I need. Thanks again for your help! But just to be sure, I take it then that there is no easy way to programatically restrict search results to topics with just the /common/topic type?